# How to change computer name in Win7 in a workgroup to make it like in a domain

Tags: windows-7, domain-name, hostname

My home computer is currently in my home's workgroup, and I don't have any domain controller in my home network. I would like to have my computer's hostname look like `mycomputer.mydomain.com`, but Windows 7 doesn't allow dot in the computer name, and since I don't have a domain controller, so I can't choose that this computer is in a domain. Is there any way to have my computer name look like a full qualified name?

Thanks.

Update: the reason I try to modify my computer name is I need to try a software that the license requires the running computer is in a particular domain. Because my home computer is just in a workgroup, the FQDN doesn't contain the domain name. I figured that if I could find a way to modify the computer name to contain the domain name, I can bypass the license check. It seems to me the only option is to set up a domain controller with the need domain name, and have the computer join the domain.

Comment: As joeqwerty said, what are you trying to achieve? There are several different ways to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the primary DNS suffix by editing the registry at:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters

and setting the `Domain` string value to the primary DNS suffix you want the computer to have.

Honestly though, I don't know what good this is going to do you. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want this?

Windows doesn't allow to have dots in the computer name. No matter if you are in a domain or on a workgroup.

The thing is that where you are in a domain your computer  full name is something like: *computername.yourdomain.com*. Your full, but the computer name continus being *computername*.
This longer name is known as [FQDN (Full qualified domain name)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) or absolute name and is use to specified the computer location in the tree hierarchy of the [Domain Name System (DNS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

When you are in a workgroup unlike domains DNS does not work for internal resolution, thats why you don't see a FQDN. But have in mind that a PC never has dots in his name.

Regards.

Comment: You certainly can run DNS in a workgroup for internal DNS name resolution.

Comment: Yes @joeqwerty you are right, it's possible. Remember that by default the names used in a workgroup eviroment are NetBios names because there are not a DNS Suffix, and they are resolve using NetBios broadcast, the Master Browser service, or a WINS server.

Comment: There are a number of ways to assign a DNS suffix to a computer in workgroup mode and also to configure a DNS suffix search list. You can assign a connection specific DNS suffix and a DNS suffix search list in the properties of the NIC or you can configure them via DHCP. If you're running a windows DNS server you simply need to set your DNS zone to allow non-secure updates and your non-domain joined computers will happily use the DNS suffix you've configured and register their A records in the DNS zone, which is maybe what the OP is after in the end.

Comment: Yes you are totally right @joeqwerty. Fully possible. Regards.

Comment: Glad to pipe in my 2 cents. :)